# HTTP Authentication using login form

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, docusignapi

So I'm trying to use REST and cURL with PHP (Codeigniter) to login into our DocuSign dev account from our custom interface. This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php

    $integratorKey = '****-********-****-****-****-************';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $username . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";
    $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($output, true);
    $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
    $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
    curl_close($ch);
?>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div id="login_form">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <?php
            echo form_open('login/hello');
            echo form_input($username, 'Username');
            echo form_password($password, 'Password');
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error I'm getting is 400. I realize that it's probably because it's sending the header before the user can input the username and password. I guess I'm not sure on how to have it "wait" until the Submit button is pressed before sending the header request. This is one of my first forays into REST and cURL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this code all on the same page? Or are you submitting the login form somewhere than handles the cURL connection?

Comment: All on the same page.

Comment: You need to wrap the code to wait for form submission, or submit the login form to separate handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are working on the same page. As such, the `$header` variables won't be populated and the request will fail.

Typically, in codeignter, you'd do something like:

Controller:

```
class Docusign extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->view('docusign_auth');
    }

}
```

View (docusign_auth_view.php)

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div id="login_form">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <?php
            // have to add the target url here in form_open
            // you also won't have values to populate the fields with
            // so no need for the $Username/$Password variables 
            // which wouldn't work like that anyway since the field name
            // goes first, not the value
            echo form_open('docusign/authenticate');
            echo form_input('username');
            echo form_password('password');
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

then back in the docusign controller, add the function to handle the form:

```
class Docusign extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->view('docusign_login');
    }

    function authenticate(){
        $post = $this->input->post();
        extract($post);
        $integratorKey = '****-********-****-****-****-************';
        $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $username . "</Username><Password>" .     $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";
        $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ( $status != 200 ) {
            echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
            exit(-1);
        }

        $response = json_decode($output, true);
        $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
        $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
        curl_close($ch);
}
```

so that you are sending the values populated in the form to a controller method that can then put them into the cURL request.

To log in, you'd visit `http://example.com/index.php/docusign` which will load `docusign_auth_view.php` in which there is a form that will be submitted to `http://example.com/index.php/docusign/authenticate` in which the variables from the form will be populated into the cURL request to send to DocuSign.

Comment: Is there any way to carry that login information throughout our site so we can access it on various pages or do you need to call that login in every controller?

Comment: Depends on how docusign works. If they return a token or session identifier you can throw that in the users session. Check their docs.